# SQL update problems

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

EDIT: found the problem

I'm having a problem with my update code, I don't know what's wrong.
I the first function sets some values, and then it is displayed in the website. When I manually edit it from the website, and run the update function, it doesn't update. There's no problem with the first function because the error is somewhere in the second. Could someone of you spot it? cause I don't.

My code:

```
function formularVisa2($antal){
        $li = MySQL_connect("database.com","login","password") or die("Kunde ej ansluta");
            MySQL_select_db("database",$li);
            if($antal==1){
                $regnr=$_POST['regnr']; 
                $marke=$_POST['marke'];
                $modell=$_POST['modell'];
                $arsmodell=$_POST['arsmodell'];
                $foto=$_POST['foto'];           
                $argid=$_POST['agarid'];        
                $ri = MySQL_query("select * from bil where regnr='$regnr' or marke='$marke' or modell='$modell' or arsmodell='$arsmodell' or agarid='$agarid'",$li);
            }

            else $ri = MySQL_query("select * from bil",$li);
            echo"<table>";
            echo '<tr><td>Regnr</td><td>Märke</td><td>Modell</td><td>Årsmod</td><td></td><td>Ägarid</td></tr>';
            while($k = MySQL_fetch_array($ri) ){                    
                echo"<form action='uppdatbil.php' method='post'>";
                echo"<tr><td><input type='text' name='regnr2' value='$k[2]' size='15' disabled='true' /></td>"; 
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='marke2' value='$k[0]' size='15' /></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='modell2' value='$k[3]' size='15' /></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='arsmodell2' value='$k[4]' size='5' /></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='foto2' value='$k[1]' size='10' /></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='text' name='agarid2 value='$k[5]' size='4' /></td>";
                echo"<td><input type='submit' name='uppdat' value='Uppdatera' /></td>";
                echo"</form>";                      
            }
            echo"</table>";
            MySQL_close($li);
        }
}

function uppdateraBil(){
            $li=MySQL_connect("database.com","login","password") or die("Kunde inte ansluta");
            MySQL_select_db("ssf_uf_se_db_1",$li);  
            $regnr2=$_POST['regnr2'];
            $marke2=$_POST['marke2']; 
            $photo2=$_POST['foto2'];     
            $modell2=$_POST['modell2']; 
            $arsmodell2=$_POST['arsmodell2']; 
            $agarid2=$_POST['agarid2'];
            MySQL_query("UPDATE bil SET marke='$marke2', foto='$photo2', modell='$modell2', arsmodell='$arsmodell2', agarid='$agarid2' WHERE regnr='$regnr2'");
            echo "vadsomhelst";
            MySQL_close($li);
            $uppdaterad="Uppdaterad";
        }
```

EDIT: fixed the MySQL_query just a few rows up:

MySQL_query("UPDATE bil SET marke='$marke2', foto='$photo2', modell='$modell2', arsmodell='$arsmodell2', agarid='$agarid2' WHERE regnr='$regnr2'");

to:

MySQL_query("UPDATE bil SET marke='$marke2', foto='$photo2', modell='$modell2', arsmodell='$arsmodell2', agarid='$agarid2' WHERE regnr='$regnr2'",$li);

There's another problem though but it's not affecting the update but that I can fix another time.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: He didn't say it gives an error, he just said it doesn't update

Comment: Upvoted as the reason for the downvote isn't obvious and isn't explained.

Comment: @JoeHarper: The issue is far from obvious too, though, and I don't see how sympathetic voting can help in making it clearer.

Comment: What does "doesn't update" mean? Is there an error message or does it fail to update silently? Have you tried displaying the UPDATE statement to see what it looks like?